# PHP, занесение данных в массив в цикле

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть такой код:

```
foreach($usersAnswers as $dataAnswers){
            var_dump($dataAnswers->user_answer);
            foreach($answers['answers'] as $key => $value){
                if($key == $dataAnswers->user_answer){

                    $countAnswer[$key] = $key;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        var_dump($countAnswer);
        exit;
```

Приходят данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда 0 == 0, и 1 == 1, то записывало это в массив с ключом 0 или 1 и плюсовало к нему +1

. То есть, должно быть, что 0 = 4, 1 = 4

Это данные в переменной $answers
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Я просто в условии сделал

```
$countAnswer[$key]++;
```

и всё заработало!